# Multiple mongodb calls in parallel to be handled concurrently using asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I need to make 3 parallel calls to mongodb collections nameed collection1, collection2 and collection3 and I need to process the data from all together after this. So instead of using sequential calls, I am trying to make concurrent calls using asyncio. I did this in the following way

```
import asyncio   

class Dash:
    async def func1():
        pipeline1 = []
        data = list(collection1.aggregate(pipeline1))
        return data
    
    async def func2():
        pipeline2 = []
        data = list(collection2.aggregate(pipeline2))
        return data
  
    
    async def func2():
        pipeline3 = []
        data = list(collection3.aggregate(pipeline3))
        return data
        


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(Dash.func1())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(Dash.func2())
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(Dash.func3())
    value1 = await task1
    value2 = await task2
    value3 = await task3
    print(value1, value2, value3)
asyncio.run(main())
```

But the time taken for completing the sequential code and this one is approximately same. few milli seconds difference only. So I checked the order of execution and I find the order of this is exactly same as sequential code. How this can be made in asynchronous way of execution using asyncio (not using motor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use async driver for mongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/motor/

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using asyncio alone ?

Comment: you'll end up with blocking operations on the driver level, so even if you run a few operations in parallel queries will be executed synchronous, you can find more information here: https://rajasimon.io/blog/mongodb-with-python-async/